# Can I contact a Steam user without befriending them?

Tags: steam

I've recently received a Steam friend request from someone I **think** I know, but I am not absolutely sure. Sadly, he has no useful information in his profile page. Is there any way I can get in touch with said user to try and figure out who they are before deciding what to do with their friend request?

Comment: You can always add them, message them, and then remove them later.

Comment: @leetfan Because to me that would be like inviting someone into your home before figuring out whether or not he is a vampire. I honestly have no idea whether friending someone is in any way exploitable, but I am the cautious sort and would rather not find out.

Comment: There is no exploit unless you take any weird trade offers and such. But they cannot do anything to you just by adding them.

Comment: @leetfan actually with some script they can find out your ip via steam voice call and try to ddos your server (this happens sometime during online tournament). However I really doubt this is the case here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A reliable way to contact another user who is not a friend is to get into a *small* group with them. If he's not part of any small groups that you can join, you can create a group and invite them to the group.

Then you can navigate to the groups under your friends list and start a chat like you would with a friend.

[image: example group]

Comment: That's actually a very nice idea. If I'm ever in this situation again, I'll be sure to try this method.

Answer (score 12):

You can send them a message via the [Steam Protocol](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_browser_protocol):

You will first need to find out that users 64bit ID, which you can do via http://steamrep.com. With this site you can also see if they are trade scammers or not.

Then add the 64bit ID to this URL:

```
steam://friends/message/id
```

Then execute it via Win+R or in your browser.

This way you open a chat with them. However, they will get a notification that asks them if they want to answer your request. If they added you anyway, they probably take it.

Steamrep.com even provides a link for that feature in their search.

[image]

They have to be online for that though.

Comment: This looks exactly like what I needed! I'll be sure to try this out.

Comment: That guy is either never online, or I can't get this to work (works just fine for people on my friends list). Can anyone else confirm this?

Comment: This answer is outdated and does not work anymore. Someone should Edit this.